# Apple Pencil only mode?

Tags: ipad, ipados, stylus

Is there any way to make the iPad or an iPad app work exclusively with the Apple Pencil and *not* recognize touch?

My issue is with notability specifically, I basically use the iPad for note-taking and "palm detection" fails a lot. I've tried multiple apps and they all fail at some point given some circumstances, so I was wondering if there's a way to make the app ignore the touch input and work only with the Pencil. I've tried Guided Access but then I can't use the pencil either...

Comment: I have a teacher for whom this is a problem, and she wears a thin cycling glove on her writing hand. She tried thin cotton gloves, but they’d fall apart too quickly and get dirty.  Think Different(ly)!

Answer (score 1):

No - even in Guided Access or [Assistive Touch (which might get you closer to your goal](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/use-assistivetouch-ipad9a2466d3/ipados) than GA) the screen is sensitive to capacitive touch.